# documentation of simple openni 1.96

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

i am trying to find out documentation of simple openni 1.96 because the old code is not suitable with simple openni 1.96. Anybody here, who know information about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zipped library in the [project's download list](https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/list) should contain a documentation directory. Open index.html from that folder in your browser.